# EF Code First: Changing model without migrations

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Code-First-Migrations is a excellent technology but for some reasons I can't use

```
static MyDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>());
}
```

So I have to turn off migrations and delete all relevant records from __MigrationHistory

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
```

When I change model I write a sql-script to make relevant changes in database.

My program has special module to execute these scripts. Such way customers can actualize their DBs when I change model. It's just part of update for them.

Does this approach have any pitfalls?

Comment: Sounds like you are writing your scripts instead of generating them from the migrations. Danger there is that you setup an incorrect relationship or setting that may cause an exception. Instead of no initializer, you might want to make sure the model matches as described here https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/

Comment: It's usefull article, thanks.
But the line
 
"!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)"

requires a chain of migrations - the thing I want to avoid.